# How to draw a DFA for that given language?

Tags: dfa

This the question : L = { vwv : w,v ∈ {a,b}* , |v| = 2 }
I draw it until W cames up idk what to do !
this is my way :

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 0):

The language defined as L = { vwv : w,v ∈ {a,b}* , |v| = 2 is associated with the regular expression:

```
{a,b}{a,b}{a,b}*{a,b}{a,b}
```

The associated DFA is:

```
       a      a         a     a
     -->--  -->--     -->--  -->--
start     s1       s2      s4      final
     -->--  -->--     -->--  -->--
       b      b   |  |  b      b
                  |  |
                a v  ^ b
                  |  |
                  |  |
                   s3
```